# Excel Macro to Insert Data into Next Row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I can't seem to figure out how to offset the information into the next row down.

What I'm trying to do is insert the same information on the next row down every time this macro is executed. I'm using it as a cheap for of Learning Management System to track completion of eLearning courses, so every time a user executes the macro it will list the date, course, and their username.

The information in `.Cells(1, 1)` is incorrect, but I just used that to ensure the rest of the macro was working. At this point I just need to figure out how build in the logic to move down one row each time the macro is executed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub Test()
    Dim objNetwork
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    strUserName = objNetwork.UserName

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("G:\Training\GPL\Test.xlsx")
    objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    objExcel.Application.Visible = False
    objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "GPL Overview"
    objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = strUserName
    objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = Date

    'objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save "G:\Training\GPL\Test.xlsx"
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "G:\Training\GPL\Test.xlsx"
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    'objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.

    'objExcel.Application.Quit
    'WScript.Echo "Finished."
    'WScript.Quit

    objExcel.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try recording what happens when you press the "down" key?

Answer (score 3):

This should fix it for you. Add this right after `objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate`

```
Dim lastrow as Long
lastrow = objExcel.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & objExcel.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1
```

And change the next three lines to this:

```
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = "GPL Overview"
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = strUserName
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lastrow, 3).Value = Date
```

**Update**

Since it looks like you are running this code inside Excel itself, I am going to show you how you can really clean this code up and allow it to run faster and be easier to decipher. See the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim strUserName as String
strUserName = ENVIRON("username")

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim objWorkbook as Workbook
Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("G:\Training\GPL\Test.xlsx")

Dim wks as Worksheet
Set wks = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)

With wks
    Dim lastrow as Long
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1

    .Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = "GPL Overview"
    .Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = strUserName
    .Cells(lastrow, 3).Value = Date

End WIth

objWorkbook.Close True

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Scott Holtzman
I had a similar problem although i had to change some settings but after few long days you came to my rescue. Thanks indeed for help. 
Here is a code i implemented and your reply helped me.

```
Private Sub Btn_Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Save.Click

        Dim MyExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        MyExcel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        wb = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\IMTIYAZ\Desktop\try")
        Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
        With ws
            Dim irow As Long
            irow = ws.Range("A65536").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            irow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
            ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value = Me.txtSn.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 2).Value = Me.txtNa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 3).Value = Me.txtGpf.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 4).Value = Me.txtBa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 5).Value = Me.txtBn.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 6).Value = Me.txtAp.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 7).Value = Me.txtBp.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 8).Value = Me.txtGp.Text
            ws.Range(irow, 9).Formula = ("=$G$3+$H$3")
            Me.Lbl_Tt.Text = ws.Cells(irow, 9).Value
            ws.Cells(irow, 10).Value = Me.txtPp.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 11).Value = Me.txtDa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 12).Value = Me.txtMa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 13).Value = Me.txtRa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 14).Value = Me.txtCa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 15).Value = Me.txtOa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 16).Formula = ("=i3+J3+K3+L3+M3+N3+O3")
            Me.Lbl_Gt.Text = ws.Cells(irow, 16).Value
            ws.Cells(irow, 17).Value = Me.txtFa.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 18).Formula = ("=P3-Q3")
            Me.Lbl_Naf.Text = ws.Cells(irow, 18).Value
            ws.Cells(irow, 19).Value = Me.txtSf.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 20).Value = Me.txtRf.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 21).Value = Me.txtSi1.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 22).Value = Me.txtSi2.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 23).Value = Me.txtSi3.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 24) = ("=S3+T3+V3+W3+U3")
            Me.Lbl_Td.Text = ws.Cells(irow, 24).Value
            ws.Cells(irow, 25).Formula = ("=R3-X3")
            Me.Lbl_Nad.Text = ws.Cells(irow, 25).Value
            ws.Cells(irow, 26).Value = Me.txtHl.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 27).Value = Me.txtCsc.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 28).Value = Me.txtMr.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 29).Value = Me.txtIt.Text
            ws.Cells(irow, 30).Formula = ("=Y3-(AC3+Z3+AA3+AB3)")
            Me.Lbl_Np.Text = ws.Cells(irow, 30).Value
            MessageBox.Show("The last row in Col A of Sheet1 which has data is " & irow)
        End With
        MyExcel.Quit()
        MyExcel = Nothing
        Me.Update()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You are adding a comment as an answer, which isn't appropriate.  After you earn enough reputation, you will be able to add your comments.